# How to write and use add rewrite rule’s code in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

After using filters in the online store, I get links like:

```
http://mysite/shop/beads/?filter_stones=agate
```

Beads is a one of the categories
agate is the selected in filters attribute which name «Stones»

I want the link to look like this:

```
http://mysite/shop/beads/beads-whith-agate
```

Everywhere in links of this type:

```
http://mysite/shop/beads/?filter_stones=agate?filter_stones= Should be replaced by category-with-attribute
```

Please tell me what the add rewrite rule code should look like to solve this problem? And how to use it?

I tried to do it with Redirection plugin, but this plugin do redirections and this is not a solution, because I need rewriting it.

Comment: What you want to do is a little bit tricky. URL parameters such as `?filter_stones=agate` is kind of fixed, in the sense that it follows a very specific format that programs can understand. Your website server can see the question mark and understand what comes after it are parameters, not another path.